# How can I select nodes in XSLT when the node is named <foo:bar>?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with a structure like this:

```
<Products>
 <Product>
  <sku>1234567</sku>
  <attribute:pa_brand xmlns:attribute="attribute">bugatti</attribute:pa_brand>
  <attribute_data:pa_brand xmlns:attribute_data="attribute_data">5|1|0</attribute_data:pa_brand>
 </Product>
</Products>
```

I'm trying to select all products from a certain brand. I tried the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Products>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Product[attribute:pa_brand  = 'bugatti']"/>
    </Products>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Product">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using XML Starlet on Mac OS it gives me: Failed to evaluate the 'select' expression.

Adding single quotes to the node name:
select="//Product['attribute:pa_brand'  = 'bugatti']"/> runs the query, but returns no results.

Using a simple node in the select, i.e.: 'sku' like this: //Product[sku='123456'] works OK. I couldn't even find out what this notation is called `<foo:bar></foo:bar>`. I don't know how the 'bar' part of the node name is called. Tried W3CSchools and various references. All examples and references, that I found, describe just simple nodes, or nodes with attributes`<foo></foo>` or `<foo bar='baz'></foo>`. Couldn't find any `<foo:bar>baz</foo:bar>` reference.

Comment: Not sure what you're using as your test environment. Your stylesheet should produce an error because the `attribute` prefix is not bound to a namespace.

Comment: For reference look at: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests.

Comment: "I couldn't even find out what this notation is called". Any book on XML will have a chapter on namespaces. You need to re-assess your approach to learning about technologies: don't leave your study of basic concepts until you hit a coding problem. You need a general understanding of what you're doing before you write a line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:attribute="attribute">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Product[attribute:pa_brand = 'bugatti']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the namespace declaration in the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: I found the solution in the meanwhile, came back to update. I learned that the notation <foo:bar> is related to namespaces and foo is a prefix in this case - which helped me to search for the solution. I noticed the xmlns:attribute="attribute" property in the XML elements and added it to the stylesheet declaration in the XSL Template as @michael.hor257k suggests. Thanks for your help.